# Load partial view depending on dropdown selection in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

Im trying to create a from using asp.net mvc3.

I have a dropdownlist with some options. 
What i want is different partial views to be injected into the page, depending on the selection in the dropdown list.

But. i dont want this to rely on a submit action. It should function so that, the partial view is loaded as soon as you select from the select list.

I have this code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create_AddEntity", new AjaxOptions { 
    UpdateTargetId = "entity_attributes", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }
))
{
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Type")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("EntityTypeList", (SelectList)ViewData["Types"])
        </div>

        <div id="entity_attributes"></div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}
```

But I can't figure out how to trigger this partial view load when the dropdown list selection changes.

This point is that the form is different for the different "entity types". so there will be loaded a different partial view, depending on the dropdown selection.

Anyone got any pointers?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Ajax or jQuery.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's say following is your view that you want to insert your partial.

```
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body>
        <!-- Some stuff here. Dropdown and so on-->
        ....

        <!-- Place where you will insert your partial -->
        <div id="partialPlaceHolder" style="display:none;"> </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

On the change event of your dropdownlist, get partial via jquery ajax call and load it to place holder.

```
/* This is change event for your dropdownlist */
$('#myDropDown').change( function() {

     /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
     var selectedID = $(this).val();

     /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
     $.get('/Controller/MyAction/' + selectedID , function(data) {

         /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
         $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
         /* little fade in effect */
         $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
     });

});
```

And in your controller action which is /Controller/MyActionin above jquery, return your partial view.

```
//
// GET: /Controller/MyAction/{id}

public ActionResult MyAction(int id)
{
   var partialViewModel = new PartialViewModel();
   // TODO: Populate the model (viewmodel) here using the id

   return PartialView("_MyPartial", partialViewModel );
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer. But is there any way to send the current model to the partial view when using this solution

Comment: @AlexCarlsen With selectedID you can also pass bunch of other data. Maybe you can serialize the current model inside your view and pass it back to server to partial action method.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi On the other hand, when the selected index is 0, the javascript method cannot be fired and the previous html data remains on the screen. How to fix it?

Comment: @Christof I don't understand why you cannot run the js, when index is 0.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi I meant the initial state of Dropdownlist with 0 (the value is like "Please Select...". So, When I select the initial value, the partial view should be gopne and the page should be the same as the initial state (theree is no partial view). Any idea?

Comment: I'm trying the exact solution, but it's not working. It's not hitting the action at all

Comment: @KrishnanduSarkar make sure that the parameter's name is the same as the configured route value. You can find it inside `global.asax.cs`. The default name is `id`

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to the header of the project (layout).
Add "combobox" to any combo box (select box) which you want to trigger the form that is surrounding it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.formcombo').change(function () {
        /* submit the parent form */
        $(this).parents("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you add the formcombo class to the select, not combobox?  Not sure where combobox is coming from....