# Show a part of HTML based on ViewBag Value ASP.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller :

```
ViewBag.Type = new[]
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Campaign Member" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Support Member" },
};
```

at my view :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Type")
    @Html.DropDownList("MemberType", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Type, "Member Type")
</div>
if (ViewBag.MemberType == "2")
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "checkbox", @type = "checkbox" })
    </div>
}
```

The Drop Down List is shown with the two options but when selecting an item nothing happens. I'm trying to show a part of HTML based on user selection at running time.

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11774933/2777098

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its passed to the view. You need to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist in javascript/jquery on the client side. And your `if` block means that if the initial value of `ViewBag.MemberType` is not `"2"` then no html will be rendered for `State`

Comment: Note also `@type = "checkbox"` is a bit pointless since the `CheckBoxFor()` method adds that anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are using "ViewBag.MemberType" in your conditional, but that object doesn't exist.  You would be better off using jquery to handle this:

```
$("#stateDiv").hide();

$("#MemberType").on("change", function () {
  if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    $("#stateDiv").show();
  }
});
```

The above code initially hides the "state"  until a value is selected from the dropdown list.  If the value selected == 2, show the "state"

Lastly, rename your "state"  to the name I provided in the sample code above:

```
<div id="stateDiv" class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "checkbox", @type = "checkbox" })
</div>
```