# after change Partial View with jquery select picker not get css

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have problem ... I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774933/2993902) to change partial view in view but when change partial view drop down not get default template css I use this jquery for refresh css :

```
      $("#SelectPicker").selectpicker('refresh');
      $("#SelectPicker").selectpicker('render');
```

with this code css is ok but dropdowns not open after use this code
[image: this is default dropdown template]
[image: this is template of dropdown after change partial view]

```
'code' function GetPartial() {
    /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
    var selectedID = $("#EstateID").val();

    /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
    $.get('/Home/ReturnProSearchPartial/' + selectedID, function (data) {

        /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
        $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);

        $(document).ready();

        $(".SelectPicker").selectpicker('refresh');
        $(".SelectPicker").selectpicker('render');
    });


}
```

Comment: You need to show **your code**. Best guess is that your replacing the element with `id="SelectPicker"` and your not attaching the plugin to the new element in the ajax success callback

Answer (score 0):

You just change the DOM, which does not mean that your css setter calls are executed. You have to execute them again after the DOM update.

Comment: how execute them ?

Comment: I use MutationObserver to detect the changes and execute my method.Or - the super-ugly solution - call the picker refresh after 100 ms with setTimeout.